# no encode delegate for this image format @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1153

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm using Paperclip, ImagMagick, Rmagick, Amazon-s3

I'm getting this error when getting an image from url and after custom resizing image replacing the changed image to amazon.

Magick::ImageMagickError (no encode delegate for this image format `//s3.amazonaws.com/beu-dev/temp_images/final_images/000/000/377/original/template_37720121205-5921-99989h.png' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1153):
  app/models/temp_image.rb:38:in`write'
line#38 is last line before end of this method

```
def reprocess_final_image
    image_file_url = self.final_image.url(:original).split('?')[0]
    thumb = Magick::Image.read(image_file_url).first
    thumb.format = "PNG"
    thumb.crop_resized!(240,200, Magick::NorthWestGravity)
    **thumb.write(image_file_url)** ***Line#38***
  end
```

Note: One more thing This code works perfectly when using system file system, but when started using amazon s3 Error happening

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the local file name instead of URL. Imagemagick can't just write the file to URL via http. To replace the source file you need to use the Amazon S3 API.

```
thumb.crop_resized!(240,200, Magick::NorthWestGravity)
thumb.write(local_temp_file_name)

# abstract Amazon S3 API. Use your favorite API
S3Object.store(local_temp_file_name, open(local_temp_file_name))
```

Comment: Thanks for instant reply
but I'm using paperclip and want to generate multi sized images, In case If I saved file localy then I've to make local file for each size of image and then upload it on amazon which will become headache when I've to maintain url of amazon not changes and upload image to same url.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.
 
1. Check "identify -list format"

If you don't see the **.jpeg format** in the list. Then you need to add the **.jpeg library**.

curl -O http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz

```
tar zxvf jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
cd jpeg-8c/
./configure
make
```

Sudo make install
Now reinstall **imagemagick** then everything works fine now.